# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API: don't understand why ModelState.IsValid always returning True, even if model should be incorrect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I've looked at other topics related to my problem, but I couldn't get it to work.

Here's my model:

```
public class UserRegister
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my controller method:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserModel>> Register([FromBody] UserRegister userRegister)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Model state: " + ModelState.IsValid);

    // Log the model data
    Console.WriteLine($"UserName: {userRegister.UserName}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Email: {userRegister.Email}");

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid form");
    }

    var newUser = await authServices.RegisterNewUser(userRegister);

    if (newUser == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("A user with this email address already exists");
    }

    return Created("somewhere", newUser);
}
```

If I send an object let's say, like this:
{
//"userName": "string",
"Password": "1111",
//"email": "test@test.ca",
"Phone": "0123456789",
"FirstName": "string",
"LastName": "string"
}

It will pass. `ModelState.IsValid` Is always true. It's not checking my model as I would like to. I don't understand why?

EDIT: Added my `Program.cs` for reference as asked by commentors

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// skiped imports

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericService<>), typeof(GenericServices<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRestaurantService, RestaurantServices>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthServices>();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MapperConfig));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opt =>
{
    opt.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyAPI", Version = "v1" });
    opt.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "bearer"
    });
    opt.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<UserModel, IdentityRole>(options =>
options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Add Authentication and JwtBearer middleware to add to Header
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = false;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            //ValidateIssuerSigningKey=true,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Secret"])),

        };
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
        // Makes my custom claim "email" discoverable by protected routes, which is not the case without. It maps the ClaimTypes.Email to "email" key.
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler
        {
            InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "email", ClaimTypes.Email }
                // Add more mappings as needed
            }
        });
    });

var supabaseUrl = builder.Configuration["Supabase:URL"];


//JSON Serializer
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore).AddNewtonsoftJson(
    options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
         {
             options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
             options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
         });


var app = builder.Build();

//Enable CORS
app.UseCors(c => c.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod());

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: With such setup, you should not be even able to hit your endpoint. Maybe there's some extra configuration that you are not showing us?

Comment: My test is invalid with your code. How is your program.cs?

Comment: I can add my `Program.cs` to my post

Comment: But had to take off some code, as it was complaining my code part was too long.

Comment: @QiangFu any insight you may think of?

Comment: I expected something override the validation in your program.cs. But no, still invalid with your program.cs.  How is the value "userRegister" received in the controller, is the fields really empty?

Comment: Yes, when I tested this, I would not send the password or email, i would skip those fields.